# Python finding the index of a repeated element in list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, position

Consider a list as follows:

> entry = [ 'document1', 'document2', 'document1', 'document2' ]

Now if I run the following piece of code:

```
for i in entry:
   print i + "has index" + entry.index(i)
```

It gives the output as

```
document1 has index 0
document2 has index 1
document1 has index 0
document2 has index 1
```

But the output should be:

```
document1 has index 0
document2 has index 1
document1 has index 2
document2 has index 3
```

Can anyone help me what should I edit in this code?

PS: I would like to use a function rather than introducing a dummy variable which is incremented along with the list.

Comment: Simply use `enumerate()`?

Comment: Yep, use `enumerate()`.

Comment: Imagine, you are going to call the `entry.index(i)` few times in exactly the same manner and you expect getting different results. You would have to call it differently to get other index. The idea of enumerate is good one.

Comment: **Why** don't you want to use a variable "which is incremented along with the list"? That's the standard, idiomatic way to handle this situation in Python (using `enumerate`, as suggested in other comments).

Comment: entry.index(i) returns the index in the list of the first item whose value is i

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own function (which uses enumerate) and use it in your code - then your *code* won't be cluttered with extraneous distrations:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def element_indices(entry):
    result = defaultdict(list)
    for ndx, element in enumerate(entry):
        result[element].append(ndx)
    return result
```

Usage:

```
entry = [ 'document1', 'document2', 'document1', 'document2' ]
for element, indices in element_indices(entry).items():
    print '{} is found at indices {}'.format(element, indices)

# >>> 
# document1 is found at indices [0, 2]
# document2 is found at indices [1, 3]
# >>>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggest, you want [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for n, item in enumerate(entry):
    print item + " has index " + str(n)
```

This is the standard, idiomatic way to do what you want in Python.

Your desire to avoid using a "dummy" variable, as you call it, is perplexing; If there is some particular reason for that restriction, it would be helpful if you mentioned that in your question.